# Thymeleaf template: image path into HTML5 attribute

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am trying to insert path to the image into HTML 5 attribute. I've tested such cases:

```
<option value="en" th:data-imagesrc="@{/images/en.png}">
  English
</option>
```

and

```
<option value="en" data-imagesrc="@{/images/en.png}">
  English
</option>
```

But both cases are failed.
What is the correct way to set HTML 5 attribute like it's th:src or th:href?

Answer (score 0):

**Use `th:attr`**

In your case

```
<option value="en" th:attr="data-imagesrc='__@{/images/en.png}__'">
  English
</option>
```

or there are 3rd party libs like created for html5 data attrs

https://github.com/mxab/thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute